# Using Template For Client Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, web-applications

My project is a desctop application with client and server side. Maybe later will be even web interface. Users can fill out different types of forms. I want use some kind of templates of this forms (on xml) and put data on client side in this templates subsequently to store user fills out a form in xml.

I'm on the right track?

1.Maybe i can use [String Template](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) or there are alternatives?

2.How can I attach a search on only some fields filled in forms, which will be stored in xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can have make a base form and use it as a template for other forms by inheriting it rather than inheriting Form.

Base form:

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected virtual void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Form you want to be based on template:

```
public partial class MainForm : BaseForm
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Here's a larger example in VB http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/GUI/InheritsfromBaseForm.htm
And some info about it from MS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983613(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: thank you for answer. But i want use template like xml that help me easier modify ui of the form.